# Extracting data from HTML table scraped with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I am pulling data from a remote website and I need to get the data inside each of the table columns.

Here is a sample of the data

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.example.com/graphs/fruit-bonanza-fruit-betsafe.html" title="Fruit Bonanza: Fruit (Betsafe)">Bonanza: Fruit (B'safe)</a></td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-48">&pound;30</td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-128">&pound;80</td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="333331" style="background-color:#f0dd66; font-weight:bold;">3d, 20h</td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-1541574886" style="background-color:#f0dd66; font-weight:bold;">128d, 2h ago</td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-94">94<strong>&deg;</strong></td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-500"><img src="https://www.example.com/imgs/green-check-small.gif"/></td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="-894">Maybe</td>
    </tr>
```

However the sorttable_customkey value is different in every instance of 
so I don't know how to go about this.
I am having to grab the data from inside the  tags as there are other elements on the page that I don't want.

Here is my code to extract the initial table data

```
$sample = file_get_contents('data/15-03-2019.php');
function getContents($str, $startDelimiter, $endDelimiter) {
  $contents = array();
  $startDelimiterLength = strlen($startDelimiter);
  $endDelimiterLength = strlen($endDelimiter);
  $startFrom = $contentStart = $contentEnd = 0;
  while (false !== ($contentStart = strpos($str, $startDelimiter, $startFrom))) {
    $contentStart += $startDelimiterLength;
    $contentEnd = strpos($str, $endDelimiter, $contentStart);
    if (false === $contentEnd) {
      break;
    }
    $contents[] = substr($str, $contentStart, $contentEnd - $contentStart);
    $startFrom = $contentEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
  }
  return $contents;
}

$array = getContents($sample, '<tbody>', '</tbody>');
  foreach($array as $link )
   {
    $removetr = str_replace('<tr>','',$link);
    $replacetr = str_replace('</tr>','<br>',$link);
    $removetd = str_replace('<td>','',$removetr);
    $replacetd = str_replace('</td>',',',$removetd);
    echo $link;
   }
```

I have tried to do a series of str_replace to remove the   tags 
and replace `</td>` with a comma and also `</tr>` with a `< br>` however because of the different values for the sortable customkey ( which are unique all the way down the page ) needless to say the replacing of the  isn't working
My end result is I'm trying to get all the data inside each column and effectively create a CSV so that the data can be imported

Struggling to explain exactly what I'm trying to do ( hopefully, someone will understand what I'm trying to say )

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time writing web scraper by your own... use the ready solution, for example this https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte or simpler this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I can use

```
preg_replace('/<td (.*?)>(.*?)<\/td>/', '$2,', $str);
```

And use multiple wildcards and then just insert the data from the 2nd instance back into where I want